# $230.$ (April, 1915) Proposed by E. B. Escott, Ann Arbor, Michigan

Tags: nt.number-theory, ho.history-overview

Just browsing some old stuff in my office for other thing I found the following:

$230.$ (April, 1915) Proposed by E. B. Escott, Ann Arbor, Michigan.

Find three numbers such that their sum, the sum of their squares, and the sum of their cubes
, shall be a cube.

Note.--W. D. Cairns says this problem, which was proposed in `L'Intermediaire` in $1900$,
remains unsolved to date, even though it was reprinted in February, $1913$.

Comment: What does "230" mean?

Comment: Number of the problem, I guess.

Comment: IF 0 is a cube, then I guess 0,0,0 is a solution...

Comment: I thought that Mr. Scott is offering 230 USD for this ;)

Comment: Move along, there's nothing to see here. 

Comment: And what is the newest development now?


Comment: @Franz: Thanks for your nice and particularly `elegant` comment...

Comment: @Luis: the faq has a couple of suggestions concerning how to ask a question and how to choose a title. Is your question the one awllower asked, or did you have something else in mind? 

Comment: The problem was proposed by E. B. Escott (not Scott), possibly the Escott of Tarry-Escott, q.v.

Comment: Edited accordingly; I used $two$ edits for: not `smart`...

Comment: Trivial solutions are those triples $(0,0,n^3)$ (up to permutation of coordinates). Are these the only "trivial" solutions? (There is no solution with a single zero, due to Fermat's last theorem for cubes, due to Euler, and no solution of the form $(n,n,\pm n)$ except $(0,0,0)$.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With a quick search from the internet I was able to only find the solution $$(146, -1314, 1168)$$  by **E. T. Bell** in *The American Mathematical Monthly*, Vol. 24, No. 5 (May, 1917), p. 240. The paper can be found from http://www.jstor.org/stable/pdfplus/2974328.pdf

(Also, a quick computer search shows that there are no positive solutions with the largest integer being less than 90000.)